# Python how to sort list of objects based on their attribute according to another list

Tags: python

That is a confusing title.

Lets say I have a list of IDs

```
ids = [3, 1, 2, 4]
```

And I am retrieving the objects in one go, for example in Django:

```
records = Record.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

How do I keep the order of records according to another list, **elegantly**, **preferably using built-in sort functions**?

The only way I can think of right now is in traditional code with minimum loops, covert the records to dictionary first, then loop through the ids to pick the record in the dictionary directly, see below:

```
result = []
dict_of_records = {r.id: r for r in records}
for id in ids:
    result.append(dict_of_records[id])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "building sort"? Google shows no relevant hits.

Comment: was a typo..... built-in.

Comment: Might be a built-in way. Anyway, a trivial algorithmic solution - you can create a hash table - key is id, value is record. Then just iterate over the sorted list of keys

Comment: @SomethingSomething please read my question, that's what I am already doing.

Comment: @JamesLin - this is not what I suggested

Comment: I suggested that you create one dictionary - where its keys are the id's, and the value of each id is the record. Then, you can iterate over the sorted list of keys of this hash, and add the records to a list that will then be a sorted list of your records

Comment: What is the difference to my current solution by loop through the ids and pick the record from a dictionary?

Comment: I'm sorry - I didn't notice that you used a beautiful dict comprehention . You're right, it is the same solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't use a sort-based solution. A sort would take O(Nlog(N)) time for N records, but we can solve the problem in O(N) time. That said, a sort would look like this:

```
positions = {j:i for i, j in enumerate(ids)}
result = sorted(Record.objects.filter(id__in=ids), key=lambda r:positions[r.id])
```

What I would do is use the `positions` table to put each record in its final position immediately:

```
result = [None]*len(positions)
for record in Record.objects.filter(id__in=ids):
    result[positions[record.id]] = record
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sorted()` and specify the sort key with the `key` keyword arg:

```
sorted(records, key=lambda x: ids.index(x))
```

this however will be **inefficient**, because it will require a lookup (`ids.index(x)`) for each record.

It will be more efficient if you precompute the sort key:

```
sortkey = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(ids)}
sorted(records, key=lambda x: sortkey[x])
```